# In the USA what state's laws do I have to abide by when rafting on a river boundary?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, water

Lets say I'm rafting in a river that marks the boundary between state A and B.  While in said river I perform an action legal in state A but not in state B.  I want to know if I broke the law.

How do I know which state's laws apply?  Is it based on whether I am closer to one state's side of the river than the other?  Do I have any defense for breaking breaking state B's law if I assumed I was still in state A's jurisdiction?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In most cases, the state boundary line controls.

For example, Kentucky owns the Ohio River along its border with Ohio, Indiana, and Illinois. In essence, the boundary between Kentucky and these three future states is the low point of the Ohio River's northernmost bank. This was established by a Congressionally passed law in 1792.

The boundary is defined by federal statute on a case by case basis for each of the rivers that is a boundary between U.S. states. Most codifications of a state's statutory laws also restate the federal statute defining the state's boundary at the beginning before the actual portion setting forth state laws begins.

In the case of the Rio Grande river, which is a boundary between the U.S. and Mexico, an international boundary treaty determines where the boundary between the U.S. and Mexico is for this purpose. International treaties similarly define all other international water boundaries of the United States.

This isn't the end of the story, however, because many activities that take place in the "navigable waters of the United States" (which basically means with respect to rivers, rivers wide and deep enough to be used for commercial transportation, like the Mississippi and Ohio Rivers and the Colorado River) are governed by federal [admiralty law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admiralty_law), rather than by state law (even if both sides of the river are in the same state).

For example, the employment law of ship crews operating on the navigable waters of the United States are governed by admiralty law, and so are most laws governing tort liability in collisions between boats/ships, and most laws governing salvage of boats/ships that have sunk.

Some admiralty law cases must be litigated in the U.S. District Courts (i.e. in the federal court system's trial courts) which have exclusive jurisdiction over some admiralty law issues, while other admiralty law issues, while still governed by federal admiralty law, may be litigated in either state or federal courts which have concurrent jurisdiction over some admiralty law issues.

Still, to the extent that admiralty law does not apply, the state law of the state in which that part of the river is located will govern.

Fun fact: As a young lawyer I once was part of a group of lawyers litigating an admiralty law case  arising out of an incident taking place on the Colorado River near Grand Junction, Colorado.

> Do I have any defense for breaking breaking state B's law if I assumed I was still in state A jurisdiction?

No. You could argue at trial that you really were in state A jurisdiction. But if the finder of fact at trial determines that you were in state B, then state B law applies.

Comment: While tangential to the OPs question, I'd also throw in "property rights" of land owners who have rivers flowing through their properties.  I don't know about other states, but this was an issue in New Mexico that was only [resolved](https://freerangeamerican.us/new-mexico-river-access/) last year

Comment: There's a fun vocabulary word to throw around in this context:  [thalweg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalweg).

Comment: Just to clarify I presume your answer means that admiralty law applies *in addition* to state law, save perhaps where they conflict?  I presumably can't hope on a raft to buy and smoke marijuana in a state where it's illegal by claiming it's not a crime under admiralty law?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Another good one is [avulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avulsion_(Common_law_jurisdictions)) "The boundary between the states is the river. Not where the river is now, mind you, but where it was back before that one heavy rainstorm in 1973, at least for this one section."

Comment: @dsollen Federal supersedes state law.  In states where marijuana is legal, it's still illegal under Federal Law (However, the Feds don't usually prosecute crimes that petty in nature and leave it to the states to deal with.).   If there is a conflict between state laws and federal laws, the federal laws are the ones that get enforced (if the Feds want to enforce them.).

Comment: @hszmv Totally off topic here, but I was listening on NPR about cannabis dispensaries, and one of the financial issues with running one is that they can't claim expenses on federal tax returns - which really cuts into the profitability.

Comment: @PeterM Yes. That section of the Internal Revenue Code is Section 280E. It has a huge impact on marijuana business law and I've dealt with tax audits related to it for clients.

Comment: @dsollen "I presume your answer means that admiralty law applies in addition to state law, save perhaps where they conflict?" The law that would apply in other parts of the territory of a state applies in all areas where it is not pre-empted by federal admiralty law. Admiralty law does not address the regulation of controlled substances.

Comment: @R.M., re avulsion.  Most of the boundary between Iowa and Nebraska near Omaha is formed by the Missouri river.  But, if you drive from the airport in Omaha to the downtown area, you pass near Carter Lake - an _Oxbow Lake_ formed by a previous course of the Missouri.  The result is that, without taking a bridge, you cross into Iowa for about a half mile and then back into Nebraska.

Comment: @Flydog57 This illustrates one of the points made in my original answer, which is that the only way to know where the boundary between states really is is to look it up on a case by case basis. Weird quirks like this are the rule and not the exception.

Comment: Fascinating!  In Europe, international and state boundaries are typically down the _centre_ of a river.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica There are examples of that in the U.S., but it certainly isn't a uniform rule and if it is the rule a majority of the time it is just barely so (and that probably depends upon how you quantify it).

Comment: It’s interesting to see a contemporary context where admiralty law actually is the answer to something, because the OPCA sovereign citizen folks like to cite it bogusly  so much, where it is totally irrelevant. I wonder where their fascination with the idea of “admiralty law” comes from and what the “kernel of truth” in it would be.

Answer (score -4):

When rafting on a river boundary in the USA, you must abide by the laws of both states that the river runs through. The same laws can vary depending on the specific river and location, but generally, you must follow the rules and regulations for boating and recreational activities in both states. This can include rules for watercraft operation, fishing, camping, and other activities. If you are unsure of the specific laws for a particular river, it is best to check with local authorities or park rangers in both states. Additionally, it is always important to exercise caution and safety while rafting on any river, regardless of state laws.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an incorrect statement of the law. It is almost never the case that the laws of more than one U.S. state will apply in a particular part of a river which is a boundary between U.S. states.